# When session expired ,do any actions will redirect login page by Django

Tags: django, session, middleware

I use `Django 1.9` and `Python 3.5`. I set session expiry time 1800 seconds.  When the session expired, I only click the url or reload the page, the page redirect the login page.  I want to do any actions on the page redirect login page.  What should I do?

my settings:

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = 
>   ( 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>   'zeus.middleware.SessionMiddleware', )

---

my middleware:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
     try:
        from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin   
     except ImportError:
        MiddlewareMixin = object

    class SessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
        def process_request(self,request):
           pass
        def process_response(self,request,response):
            if hasattr(request,'user'):
                if request.user.is_authenticated():
                    request.session.set_expiry(1800)
            return  response
```

Comment: If the session is expired the call to the server cannot contain any information on the user who is trying to access - so it is the same as when a new user is trying to load the page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When the session is expired,I do any actions on the page,for example,I query some information or edit information ,it redirect login page,not when I reload the page, it redirect login page.Can it possible?

Comment: It should be possible but I am not aware of any simple way to do this. You might need to look into the session implementation in django.